# Best way to use dataframe inside a class?

Tags: python, pandas

Which version is the more appropriate one?

```
# First version
class Myclass:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def import_data(self):
        ''' import data  '''
        df = pd.read_excel('link to data')
        return df

    def add_return(self, df):
        ''' add returns '''
        df['Return'] = (df['Close'] / df['Close'].shift() -1)
        return df

test = Myclass()
data = test.import_data()
data = test.add_return(data)

##################################################################

# Second version
class Myclass:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def import_data(self):
        ''' import data  '''
        self.df = pd.read_excel('link to data')
        return self.df

    def add_return(self):
        ''' add returns '''
        self.df['Return'] = (self.df['Close'] / self.df['Close'].shift() -1)
        return self.df

test = Myclass()
test.import_data()
test.add_return()
```

As you can see the main difference is the use of self for the dataframe.
What would be the best way to use pandas dataframe in a class

Thank you for your help.

Comment: In the second example, `test.add_return(data)` is passing an argument when there isn't any, no? In any case, this will depend on the rest of the program, how you're using the DataFrame, etc.

Comment: you're right, the second test.add_return() should not take an argument. I just edit the code. thanks AMC